# Effect of PWM output from Variable Frequency Drive to PSC motor

Tags: vfd, ac-motor

I looked at VFD diagram and seem like it use Sine-PWM Output without any filter to drive psc single phase ac motor
Inductance and capacitance seem to work with pure sine wave but PWM output have a lot of harmonic frequency.
The question are as following.

1. can we put PWM output directly to motor, how the system behave?
2. Does it need additional filter to convert pwm to sine wave?
3. Is that practical?, how we do for practical use?

[image]

Comment: I think this question is too complex for this forum. For PWM implemented on the DC side, I think you should have a large capacitor on the output side of the PWM. You could also do PWM using the inverter rather on the DC side. PSC motors do not necessarily have main winding identical to aux winding. This scheme probably requires them to be identical. Results would probably be better with 90 degree phase voltage displacement. Do you have any published design guidance for this scheme? I don't think this has been done except for motors designed for this specific scheme.

Comment: OMG, I think I figured its out!.

Comment: If we can create to phase shifted  waveform then we don’t need capacitor , problem solve